# groovy cannot find matching class constructor issue (see last comment)

Tags: grails, groovy

PLEASE SEE LAST COMMENT ON QUESTION:

The following code compiles but I can't figure out why I get a runtime error:

```
 def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
   ...
 SSLSocketFactory sf = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
```

I have an import statement:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

and searching on the web the [class definition is here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html).

I see one of the constructors is deprecated, i.e.

```
 SSLSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext, HostNameResolver nameResolver)
```

but there is

```
 SSLSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext, X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier)
```

So shouldn't this work fine?  PLEASE NOTE I DON'T GET THIS ERROR IF I DROP THE 2nd CONSTRUCTOR argument.

The error I get running grails 2.2.3 is:

```
Class: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext, org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier)
```

Comment: Please see further clarification made in question that may help, i.e. PLEASE NOTE I DON'T GET THIS ERROR IF I DROP THE 2nd CONSTRUCTOR argument.  But I believe I will need a second constructor argument for this code to do its intention.

Comment: So you realize this has nothing to do with Grails, or Groovy for that matter? Just saying you might get better help with appropriate tags.

Comment: James -- why is this not a Groovy issue?  Are you saying Groovy is correct in it's run-time error reporting, that this constructor really doesn't exist, and so it's a Java issue?

Comment: So Codelark helped me by pointing out I could use the single argument constructor and then make a call to set the hostnameVerifier, i.e.  sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER). This does work, so I'm okay without making the constructor work, but kept the question because perhaps someone is close to solving it.

Comment: I was saying this isn't a groovy issue because its not a Groovy class. I suppose there could be a bug in Groovy causing the issue but that seems unlikely.